# Alternative to find() for determining whether an unordered_set contains a key

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-set

Suppose I have an `unordered_set<int> S` and I wanna to check if it contains a certain `int x`.

Is there a way for me to write something like `if(S.contains(x)){ /* code */ }` that works like `if(S.find(x) != S.end()){ /* code */ }` ?

It can be a macro or anything but I just find it ugly and unnecessarily long to write a simple lookup method like that.

Comment: C++20 has `contains` as a method on the std::unordered_set.

Comment: Pre C++20, you can do this `bool set_contains(unordered_set<int> s, int value) { return s.find(value) != s.end(); }`, and then use it `if(set_contains(S, x))...`.

Comment: Glory to C++20 ! The STL seems much more targeting performance than usage convenience. That's why I prefer using Qt containers whenever possible

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using `std::unordered_set`'s `find()` member function for determining whether a given key `x` is present as in:

```
if (S.find(x) != S.end()) { /* code */ }
```

you can simply use the [`count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/count) member function:

```
if (S.count(x)) { /* code */ }
```

An `std::unordered_set` does not allow duplicates, so `count()` will return either `0` or `1`.

---

The `unordered_set::count()` member function shouldn't be less efficient than `unordered_set::find()` since the traversal of the elements for finding out the count of the requested key can be stopped as soon as one is found because there can't be duplicates.

Comment: Oh, sorry, with @Hanzhou answer it is clear to me now. I think I'll just create a macro `#define contains(x) count(x)`. Thank you!

Comment: Optimized code means 1) macros have no advantages over a simple function, consider "bool contains(int x) {return S.count(); }.", and B) a function obeys C++ scope rules, which macro's ignore.  The symbol "contains" is a common enough function name to cause you grief when also used as a macro.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `if(S.count(x)){//do something}`.
According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/count/), the count function searches the container for elements with a value of k and returns the number of elements found. Because unordered_set containers do not allow for duplicate values, this means that the function actually returns 1 if an element with that value exists in the container, and zero otherwise.